# C# code blocks in class

Tags: c#, class, syntax

In java, I can write code like this.

```
public class Map1 extends MapInfo {

    {
        // I can access fields of the super class
    }

}
```

Currently writing this code in sharpdevelop the code completion didnt show up.

```
public class Map1 : MapInfo {

    {
        // It gives error.
        // Invalid token '{' in class, struct, or interface member declaration (CS1519) - C:\Users\sriharshach....st\Map.cs:10,3
    }

}
```

Is there a way to write the same code in c#? (i.e, not in the constructor)

Thanks

Comment: If the fields are `public` or `protected` you should be able to access them just as if they were fields of that derived class. `private` fields of the super-class are only accessable by the superclass itself.

Comment: What is this code supposed to be? A code block that's no constructor/method? When would that code run?

Comment: Could you clarify the what you are trying to do or provide a more concrete example?  In C# you can access fields of the superclass without doing anything special, as long as they are not marked as private.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in C# land it would be

```
public class Map1 : MapInfo
{
   // You can access protected and public fields / methods from the SuperClass
   // and internal + protected internal 
}
```

**edit:** Had too many curly braces and fixed up comment

Comment: Also `internal` and `protected internal` :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer, as in Java, depends on the access level of the fields.  Assuming that the fields are not private, you should be able to access superclass fields just as if they belonged to the child class.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can access not-private fields of super class everywhere you want in derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can inherit/implement base class using `:`,  You cannot use {} immediately in a class. You need methods or constructor name followed by {}

For example

```
public class ParentFoo {
  public Parentfoo() {}
}

public class ChildFoo:ParentFoo -- inheriting parentfoo
{
   public ChildFoo(){}
}
```